# pass parameter to 2nd function jsom

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

Hi  I have the following code, how can I pass oList into function onQuerySucceeded?

```
function lockMandaysItems(tID,oList) {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(oList);

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'TeamRequest\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Number\'>'+ tID +'</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Added in 1st function:
  this.myParam = "Hello SharePoint World";

then available in called function

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to do what I have done in below code.

```
<script>
    var listItemInfo = '';
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js");

    function retrieveListItems() {
        retrieveSingleList('/sites/xxx/yyy', 'mylist');
        retrieveSingleList('/sites/xxx/zzz', 'mylist');
    }

    function retrieveSingleList(siteURL, listName) {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteURL);
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' +
            '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query></View>');
        this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.load(collListItem);
        var mySuccessCallBack = Function.createCallback(onQuerySucceeded, this.collListItem);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, mySuccessCallBack), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }

    function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args, PcollListItem) {
        var listItemEnumerator = PcollListItem.getEnumerator();
        listItemInfo += '<table border=1><tr><td>ID</td><td>Title</td><td>Likelihood</td><td>Event</td></tr>';
        while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
            listItemInfo += '<tr><td>' + oListItem.get_id() +
                '</td><td>' + oListItem.get_item('Title') +
                '</td><td>' + oListItem.get_item('Likelihood') +
                '</td><td>' + oListItem.get_item('Event');
            listItemInfo += '</td></tr>';
        }
        listItemInfo += '</table>';
        document.getElementById("RollupPlaceHolder1").innerHTML = listItemInfo.toString();
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        document.getElementById("RollupPlaceHolder1").innerHTML = ('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to make 2 changes

**1.** Change the definition of onQuerySucceeded function to contain your variable oList.

**2.** Change the way you call this success function.

Refer below the updated code.

```
function lockMandaysItems(tID,oList) {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(oList);

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'TeamRequest\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Number\'>'+ tID +'</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function () { onQuerySucceeded(oList); }, queryFail);        

}

function onQuerySucceeded(oList) {
}

function queryFail() {
}
```

Comment: The code doesnt work. Are you sure sender, args need to be omitted?

Comment: What problem are you facing? I have updated answer for queryFail function, may be this was a problem. Also as far as my experience is concerned removing sender and args do not cause a problem unless you use it inside a function or pass values from somewhere else.